# Not able to open Chrome headless from Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am using maven here.Here is my Selenium code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capb = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capb.setCapability("chrome.binary","/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless","--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox","--remote-debugging-port=9222");
    capb.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/nitinkumar/TEST/chromedriver");
    try{
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capb);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://qa.cmnetwork.co");
    driver.quit();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when I run "mvn test" it starts the chrome in GUI mode. but It should open in Headless mode. I have **chrome vesrion 59.0**, **OS X yosemite(10.10.5)**, **chromedriver 2.30** and **Selenium 3.4.0**.

Comment: It's worth to mention **`Headless mode is available on Mac and Linux in Chrome 59. Windows support is coming in Chrome 60. To check what version of Chrome you have, open chrome://version.`**

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question. I made it bold now.

Comment: how about setting option like `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Comment: tried but still open in GUI mode not in headless mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't open in GUI mode. Just the chrome launcher icon will be opened. And it is an expected behaviour.

You have to remove the argument `--remote-debugging-port`. That will block the launched headless Chrome. So the script will never move forward.And you will get a `chrome not reachable` error

So change the arguments like

```
options.addArguments("--headless","--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox");
```

Also, there is no need for `--no-sandbox`. As per [Official doc](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) only `--headless` and `--disable-gpu` flags are enough

Unless you have multiple versions of chrome installed, there is no need for `DesiredCapabilities` as well.

So the simple code for headless-chrome

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("--headless","--disable-gpu");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","/Users/nitinkumar/TEST/chromedriver");

    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("https://qa.cmnetwork.co");
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: I would suggest just to keep --no-sandbox. Keeping --disable-gpu argument doesn't show chrome UI via selenium in Linux (in my little experience).