# Selenium with Crome and Maven not works. ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials

Tags: java, maven, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu

I want to run **headless Chrome** with **`Selenium`**, but this code not works:

```
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    File file = new File("/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

It compiles fine, but at runtime crashes with stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.java:39)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:184)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:158)
    at org.chrome.automation.Starter.main(Starter.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 8 more
```

The POM contains just two dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I thought the problem in Selenium dependencies, as they are rely on some apache code but not download dependent components. I tried to add apache dependencies like:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

But problem persists.

Please help to run selenium with headless Crome.

Comment: Make sure that this class exists on classpath. try to open it in eclipse. If it doesn't open try to download jar manually

Comment: I checked and know what? It is in my classpath! I tried to delete all dependencies except chrome driver only. And it is still in classpath. The jar file with it named httpclient-4.5.3.jar.

Comment: Also, you need to add `--disable-gpu`. As it is a recommended approach [from Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44780826/3122133)

Comment: @Madhan As you can see the stacktrace is about missed Class: NoClassDefFoundError. How could this argument resolve? I ask because when I tried I get same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve by using just one dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Also it works with 3.3.1, 3.2.0. As I see the problem happen in 3.4.0 version only.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, not only with chrome but with other browses too. 
seems, there were some jars missing, do following and it should fix the issue:

1. Close the eclipse
2. Go to "C:\Users\myuser.m2\repository" folder and delete all the files and folder from here
3. Open elclipse, select your project and do alt+f5 and check option Force Update of Snapshots.
4. Wait till it builds, it should be fixed now.

Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Specifying explicit dependency on `selenium-chrome-driver` is **definitely wrong**, as `selenium-java` already contains this.

To get Chrome running in headless mode, you need Chrome minimum version 59 (version 60 on Windows), and the following code:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ...);
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.addArguments("headless", "disable-gpu");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

`disable-gpu` is required as an option; see [this discussion](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) for more details.

Comment: I think your answer misleading. If you mention something definitely wrong, you should add the right solution and mention that thing you called wrong works fine, just ads one more dependency import. This is not prevent chrome driver to work properly. Right? Also you can take a look at my couple weeks old answer. The problem happen with selenium-chrome-driver 3.4.0 only.

Comment: @Pavlo I'm using 3.4.0 with no problems.

Comment: I just cannot get deeper because not have resource to check all the environment details and compare my and your config. It could work for somebody, but for me it is not. Thanks for your efforts to let me know more about this.